# Apache Tuning doubts

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to tune the parameters in apache for a high traffic website. My specs are

```
Ram : 12 GB RAM
CPU : 16 core
```

Current Parameters

```
StartServers 5
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 10
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 10
ServerLimit 2500
MaxClients 2500
MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
KeepAlive Off
KeepAliveTimeout 5
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
```

What is the advised values for this parameters according to my server specs?

Comment: MaxClients can be determined by taking amount of free RAM you can dedicate to Apache divided it by the number of memory size your concrete individual Apache process consumes. Roughly the maximum Apache can use is in case of PHP MaxClients * (max_memory from php.ini + how much Apache process weighs itself).

Comment: Your MaxClients is ridiculously high - unless the average size of an httpd process is like around 4MB (doubtful).

Answer (score 0):

The number of workers you can spawn (that usually is defined by the maxclients directory in the type of MPM in use for PHP) depeneds on the size of each worker and the memory you got available on the machine.

For instance (and here I am doing quick calculation, not pointing to accuracy), if you have 12 GB, you should consider that part of them will be used by the kernel for its own usage, for buffering, other libraries etc.

Let's say (rough estimation) that 2 GBs go away for the stuff I have aforementioned.

At this point you remain roughly with 10 GB of RAM.

Now, let have as per example that each worker takes 100 MBs of RAM (this depends on module you load on Apache and the sizing of PHP you are doing).

This means that you would be able to roughly serve 10.000 (RAM) / 100 (size of worker) users which results in about 100 concurrent users. Which is not bad considering that there are considerations to be done about the keepalive directive, how long you keep alive a sessions, the speed you have to generate content (and therefore free the worker).

A golden rule in web hosting is to never swap. If you start swapping you are over, game over. Swap is detrimental in any system but particularly for web services.

If you swap, you start accumulating workers (because you will be slow to serve users) and most probably you will auto inflict a DOS (Denial of service) in you system in a matter of minutes.

Again, there is no gold rule, my calculations are by approximation, just as an example.

I suggest to:

- Setup your test environment
- Tune the system
- Tune Apache
- Tune PHP
- Load you app
- Simulate load
- See what is the threshold before you start swapping
- Configure apache and php with the findings of the above points

I hope this helps in some way.